# BASH: How to extract substring that is surrounded by specific text

Tags: bash, extract

I am trying to extract numbers from file names that follow a specific pattern:

```
file-8923489_something.txt
another_file-8923489_something.txt
some-other_file-8923489_something.txt
```

I want to extract the number that is between text "file-" and "_something" that will work with the above 3 file names.

What is the best way to go about this?

Is it possible to do this using operators only, such as ## and %%?  How about something like:

```
filename=file-8923489_something.txt
file=${${filename##*file}%%_something}}
```

However, it didn't work as I expected.

Answer (score 2):

Using pre BASH regex:

```
x="some-other_file-8923489_something.txt"
[[ "$x" =~ file-([0-9]*)_something ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
8923489
```

OR this `grep -P` will also work:

```
grep -oP "file-\K\d+(?=_something)" file
8923489
8923489
8923489
```

OR using awk:

```
awk -F 'file-|_something' '{print $2}' file
8923489
8923489
8923489
```

Answer (score 0):

With `grep`:

```
$ echo "file-8923489_something.txt
another_file-8923489_something.txt
some-other_file-8923489_something.txt" | grep -Po '(?<=file-)\d+'
8923489
8923489
8923489
```

Or with pure `bash`:

```
d="your_string"
d1=${d%_*}
your_final_string=${d1##*-}
```

#### Test

```
$ d="file-8923489_something.txt"
$ d1=${d%_*}
$ echo $d1
file-8923489
$ echo ${d1##*-}
8923489

$ d="some-other_file-8923489_something.txt"
$ d1=${d%_*}
$ echo $d1
some-other_file-8923489
$ echo ${d1##*-}
8923489

$ d="another_file-8923489_something.txt"
$ d1=${d%_*}
$ echo $d1
another_file-8923489
$ echo ${d1##*-}
8923489
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to do this using operators only, ...

```
$ filename="file-8923489_something.txt"
$ file=${foo//[^0-9]/}
$ echo $file
8923489
```

You might want to refer to [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Alternatively, you can say:

```
$ file=$(tr -dc '[[:digit:]]' <<< "$filename")
$ echo $file
8923489
```